# Произвольные поля WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, acf

через плагин ACF создаю произвольные поля, и заполняю их, и вот у меня возник вопрос при создании дочерних страниц, возможно ли значения с произвольных полей переносить на дочерние страницы автоматически, а не каждый раз переносить инфу с каждой страницы? при создании дочерних страниц произвольные поля становятся пустыми

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В цикле WordPress дочерней страницы надо получить id родительской страницы и использовать ACF родителя.

```
$global $post;

$parent_id = $post->post_parent;
$field = get_field( 'field_name', $parent_id );
```

Comment: то есть мне нужно сделать новый шаблон для дочерней страницы, и в нем получать поля родителя и вставлять в нужные мест? я просто изначально хотел использовать шаблон родителя но получается так не получится

Comment: при чем тут шаблон? он может быть одинаковым. $post у вас разный в этом шаблоне. if примените, чтобы отличить родителя от потомка.